# Can a matrix have equal range and null spaces and non-zero eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A square matrix can have the same range and null spaces; such as the matrix below;
\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}

This matrix and all the matrices I figured out to have the same range and null spaces have zero eigenvalues. Is there any matrix that have non-zero eigenvalues and same range and null spaces?

If not, why it needs to have zero eigenvalues? Is there any formal way to describe?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! If the eigenvalues of a matrix are non-zero, its null space is $\{0\}$, and if further, range and null space are equal, it is the $0$ matrix.

Comment: @Bernard That explains why there must be a zero eigenvalue, not why all the eigenvalues must be zero.

Comment: @Bernard Thank you!

Comment: Suppose $\lambda0$ is an eigenvalue; $Ax=\lambda x$ for some $x\ne0$. Now $Ax$ lies in the range of $A$, which is the nullspace: $A(Ax)=0$. So $\lambda^2x=0$, and since $x\ne0$ this shows that $\lambda=0$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thanks for the clarification!